# Parallel RLC circuit

Tags: ac

I am beginning to learn AC circuits and am trying to analyze the following RLC circuit:
[image]

I want to find the real-time voltage across the resistor. I believe I will do this by finding the current with I = V_p / Z then use that current to find the voltage on the resistor. I'm not sure how to calculate Z in a parallel circuit. Would I do Z = (1/(Z_R + Z_C) + 1/Z_L)^-1 as I would with resistors in parallel?

Comment: There's a voltage divider formed by R and C, so no need to bother with L

Comment: Paraphrasing @chu, you have a perfect voltage source that puts a 141.42V RMS sinewave across the series combination of R1 and C2 - the inductor is nothing to do with finding the voltage across R1.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. How do I then only deal with R1 then? I'm a little confused on AC circuits.

Comment: @Andyaka and does that mean there is no current going through L1?

Comment: The same voltage appears across L, and the series combination of R & C. You can apply Ohm's Law to both of these branches separately to work out the currents through them. But to work out the voltage across R you only need to treat R and C as a voltage divider - no need to find the current and then multiply by R.

Comment: There could be a gazillion amps flowing thru L1 but still there would be 141.42 volts across it (and R1 in series with C2). BTW what happened to C1 LOL?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, when in parallel combination,
1/(Znet) = 1/Z1 + 1/Z2 + 1/Z3 .....